# how to install atom-beautify using command line in the terminal

Tags: command-line

i have been trying to install atom-beautify through the terminal by running the command apm install atom beautify but it returned request for package failed.
am using ubuntu 16.4
kindly assist

Comment: run apm install atom-beautify

Comment: have done it but still it says package error

Comment: what kind of error you have can you add screenshot?

Comment: it write package error

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on the web, I found a PPA that may give access to the atom package. These 3 commands;

sudo add apt repository ppa:webupd8team/atom

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install atom

after this install the atom-beautify package should be available.

Comment: i have installed the atom but the problem is how i can i can install the atom-beautify package...it fail to install whenever i try installing